# Doctrine CASE WHEN THEN ELSE NULL

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a repository function and I want to use CASE WHEN THEN ELSE, but doctrine doesn't allow NULL in ELSE. Sure, i googled, but I couldn't find an answer how to avoid it.

```
public function countAverageOdd($user) {
    return $this->getEntityManager()
                    ->createQuery('
                            SELECT
                                avg(
                                    CASE
                                        WHEN p.homeAway = \'h\' AND p.moneyline IS NOT NULL THEN m.home
                                        WHEN p.homeAway = \'d\' AND p.moneyline IS NOT NULL THEN m.draw
                                        WHEN p.homeAway = \'e\' AND p.moneyline IS NOT NULL THEN m.away
                                        WHEN p.homeAway = \'h\' AND p.spread IS NOT NULL THEN s.home
                                        WHEN p.homeAway = \'e\' AND p.spread IS NOT NULL THEN s.away
                                        WHEN p.homeAway = \'h\' AND p.total IS NOT NULL THEN t.over
                                        WHEN p.homeAway = \'e\' AND p.total IS NOT NULL THEN t.under
                                    ELSE NULL
                                    END
                                    )
                            FROM
                                AppBundle:Predictions p
                                LEFT JOIN p.moneyline m
                                LEFT JOIN p.spread s
                                LEFT JOIN p.total t
                            WHERE p.user = :user ')
                    ->setParameter(":user", $user)
                    ->setMaxResults(1)
                    ->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

Error:
**[Syntax Error] line 0, col 900: Error: Unexpected 'NULL'**

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/3160

*doctrinebot commented on 22 May 2013*

*Issue was closed with resolution "Won't Fix"*

Please, give me advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to bypass Doctrines logical checks by passing in the null value as a parameter. It's a hack, but it seems to be the only thing that works,.

```
public function countAverageOdd($user) {
    return $this->getEntityManager()
                    ->createQuery('
                            SELECT
                                avg(
                                    CASE
                                        WHEN p.homeAway = \'h\' AND p.moneyline IS NOT NULL THEN m.home
                                        WHEN p.homeAway = \'d\' AND p.moneyline IS NOT NULL THEN m.draw
                                        WHEN p.homeAway = \'e\' AND p.moneyline IS NOT NULL THEN m.away
                                        WHEN p.homeAway = \'h\' AND p.spread IS NOT NULL THEN s.home
                                        WHEN p.homeAway = \'e\' AND p.spread IS NOT NULL THEN s.away
                                        WHEN p.homeAway = \'h\' AND p.total IS NOT NULL THEN t.over
                                        WHEN p.homeAway = \'e\' AND p.total IS NOT NULL THEN t.under
                                    ELSE :null
                                    END
                                    )
                            FROM
                                AppBundle:Predictions p
                                LEFT JOIN p.moneyline m
                                LEFT JOIN p.spread s
                                LEFT JOIN p.total t
                            WHERE p.user = :user ')
                    ->setParameters(array(":user"=> $user,":null"=>NULL))
                    ->setMaxResults(1)
                    ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: I can try it in the next Monday and I'll post the result.

Answer (score 6):

Another hack is to use `NULLIF`,which is [supported](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/v2.5.4/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php#L1936). 
e.g

```
CASE WHEN WHEN p.homeAway = \'h\' THEN 'xyz' ELSE NULLIF(1,1) END
```

Got this from https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/5801#issuecomment-336132280

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

checkout out the [myql case operator documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case). The `ELSE` is optional, so you can just remove it

```
public function countAverageOdd($user) {
    return $this->getEntityManager()
                    ->createQuery('
                            SELECT
                                avg(
                                    CASE
                                        WHEN p.homeAway = \'h\' AND p.moneyline IS NOT NULL THEN m.home
                                        WHEN p.homeAway = \'d\' AND p.moneyline IS NOT NULL THEN m.draw
                                        WHEN p.homeAway = \'e\' AND p.moneyline IS NOT NULL THEN m.away
                                        WHEN p.homeAway = \'h\' AND p.spread IS NOT NULL THEN s.home
                                        WHEN p.homeAway = \'e\' AND p.spread IS NOT NULL THEN s.away
                                        WHEN p.homeAway = \'h\' AND p.total IS NOT NULL THEN t.over
                                        WHEN p.homeAway = \'e\' AND p.total IS NOT NULL THEN t.under

                                    END
                                    )
                            FROM
                                AppBundle:Predictions p
                                LEFT JOIN p.moneyline m
                                LEFT JOIN p.spread s
                                LEFT JOIN p.total t
                            WHERE p.user = :user ')
                    ->setParameter(":user", $user)
                    ->setMaxResults(1)
                    ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: maybe I was too quick to answer, I did not check if this is actually supported by Doctrines DQL, but I will do. Can you post the according *runnable query* from the symfony profiler?

Comment: an alternative way to dql would be to set this up as a [native doctrine query](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html), which should not be a problem as you only return a single scalar result

Comment: else is required for doctrine